# In stripe transfer getting error "No such destination: default_for_currency"

Tags: stripe-payments, transfer, stripe-connect, payout

I am using stripe php sdk in laravel application , where seller user adds dummy bank account number and routing number in bank detail.
Now seller payout his stripe balance into their bank account using below strip Transfer api-

```
function payout()
{
    Stripe::setApiKey($this->secret_key);
    $balance = Balance::retrieve();
    $balance = $balance->available[0]->amount;

    if ($balance == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    $transfer = Transfer::create([
        "amount" => $balance ,
        "currency" => 'gbp',
        "destination" => 'default_for_currency',
        "description" => config('app.name') . ' payout.'
    ]);

    if ($transfer->failure_code !== null) {
        throw new Exception($transfer->failure_message);
    }

    $transaction = new StripeTransfer();
    $transaction->user_id = $this->user_id;
    $transaction->stripe_id = $transfer->id;
    $transaction->amount = $balance;
    $transaction->save();

    return true;
}
```

But this gives below error-

```
"No such destination: default_for_currency"
```

I am using it in test env. May this effecting. Please help in provide good solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `destination` should be a valid Stripe account id. e.g. something like `"acct_1HKbBD2oxnBfnQ8N"`